# DataTemplateSelector and its weird behavior

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, datatemplate

I am using a `DataTemplateSelector` inside a `ContentControl`. I have 3 different `DataTemplates` based on 3 different `object types`. When I set the `content` of my `ContentControl` to data of the mentioned types, the `DataTemplateSelector` swaps to the specific `DataTemplate` AND the selector futhermore seems to rollback/reset the values from the old template. Why is that so?

**Edit:** I figured out that the values get resetted because I have an attached property caled Prop and inside its OnPropertyChangedCallback it notifies me about the Prop having value null on swapping between DataTemplates. You can see that attached property in code below.

Can somebody help me out what happens behind this swapping mechanism of `DataTemplateSelector`?

Here is a deeper explaination with code:

```
public void Window1()
{
  InitalizeComponents();
}

public void OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  if(this.DataContext == null)
    this.DataContext = "Hallo";
 else{
  if(this.DataContext is string)
    this.DataContext = 123;
  else{
   if(this.DataContext is int)
     this.DataContext = null;
   }
  }
}
By clicking on Button few times I change the type and so in ContentControl the selector changes to DataTemplate.
```

The selector looks like this below. It swaps between `textDataTemplate` and `numericDataTemplate` and one more template. As I mentioned i have those three type which are `string`, `int`, `and one more`, that i wish not to metion. Their `DataTemplates` are called `textDataTemplate`, `numericDataTemplate` and that one more. :)

```
<local:MyTemplateSelector x:Key="dataTemplateSelector"
                                 TextTemplate="{StaticResource textDataTemplate}"
                                 NumericTemplate="{StaticResource numericDataTemplate}"/>

public class MyTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
  public DataTemplate TextTemplate;

  public DataTemplate NumericTemplate;


  public DataTemplate Select(object item, Culture.....)
  {
    if(item is string)
    {
      return this.TextTemplate;
    }
    else
    {
      return this.NumericTemplate;
    }
  }
}
```

`ContentControl` and XAML looks like this:

```
<Button Click="OnClick" Content="Click Me"/>


<ContentControl Name="contentCtrl"
                Content="{Binding}"
                Width="123"
                ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource dataTemplateSelector}" />
```

And this is how `textDataTemplate` looks alike.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="textDataTemplate">
    <TextBox  x:Name="text" my:AttProperties.Prop="{extension:MarkupExt value}" Text="{Binding Path=Txt, Mode=Default, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

`numericDataTemplate` looks similar to `textDataTemplate` just that only digits are allowed.

The `Prop` is my `attached property` from `AttProperties class` of `type string`. The `Prop` is somewhere inside of all three DataTemplate. Above the `Prop` is sitting on a `TextBox` but it could be a `Label` too. The `markupextension` is just a **"return Hello"**. The extension is just there to test how to create a custom markupextension. There is no big deal with the extension. It shouldnt have to do much with the swapping of `DataTemplates`.

One more time to explain my problem. Swapping seems reselts/rollback my old templates. I swap from textDataTemplate to lets say numericDataTemplate and the Prop of textDataTemplate gets set to null but the value before was "Hello".

Why is that happening? It seems like the same behavior with using `tiggers`. Once a `Trigger` is no more valid it rollsback the used values. Is a `DataTemplateSelector` using some kind of same mechanism as `Triggers`?

**Edited**:
The attached property is just a simple .RegisterAttached with an OnPropertyChangedCallback. Inside OnPropertyChangedCallback I figured the prop is null when swapping the dataTemplates.

Comment: Do you have any specific issue or is it 'just want to know' question?

Comment: Can you post the template and the view please? IMHO I don't think, that the `Template` is recreated again and again.

Comment: I edited my question with code and more explaination.

Comment: Hmm...difficuilt to tell. How is the `AttachedProperty` implemented?

Comment: Very simple. Its just an attachedproperty with a private static OnPropertyChanged. Inside that method i call MessageBox.Show(e.NewValue). OnPropertyChanged gets called which means the attached dp does work.

Comment: I edited my question one more time. I am giving you 50 points for this answer. IF you can answer me.

Comment: Well to get the whole view of the problem, you should also post the implementation of `MyTemplateSelector`.

Comment: Its a 2 line code with an if(typeof(..) == string) return TextTemplate else return NumericTemplate... its easy.. you can see the selector in xaml above.

Comment: Well the XAML is only declaration. You have to know the mechanisms behind, so that you're able to interpret what's happening. So .cs code speaks louder than xaml code of custom classes. ;o)

Comment: Yea like i said its just an If statement. Pretty simple. Nothing else. swapping works. There is no extra code inside the .cs file of selector except the if .. then return textTempalte or numericTemplate. Actually if you wish to have an conversation with me, why not start a chat room hehe. Lets keep this clean for others who might know how to solve this.

Comment: What is the question? What exactly doesn't work and how do you switch templates?

Comment: When selector switchs the datatemplate it seems to resets values of elements and properties inside the old datatemplate. I get an propetychanged from my attachedproperty that on switching the value is null hence value is reseted. I dont switch datatemplate the contentcontrol is doing that for me. By asking questions like this it seems to me you arent very familar with datatemplateselectors or datatemplates so please no offence but lets not make this thread full of "less helpful" comments. No offence. I will gift 50 points to right answer.

Comment: What does it mean that you don't switch data templates? It's a complete nonsense, they can't be switched by magic. Maybe you use a different framework instead of WPF, but in real WPF and C# there is a code that switches data templates and there is a model that is bound to this template. So the request of C# code still remains, if you don't want to add all code to the question - I doubt that anyone could guess what is wrong.

Comment: lol vorrtex I DONT SWITCH it by code.. as soon you change the contentcontrol.content property selector gets called and switches the datatemplate.. its WPF engine automatically switching for me or as you would say it.. its really the magic of wpf that does it for me.. learn more about wpf and the come back here.. one more thing there is no more code.. its a simple application.. its all happening in xaml as i described.

Comment: I edited the code and my question. Please take a look again.

Comment: @snowyguihedgehog -.- You don't really understand the way of asking, do you? Well being offensive and rude animates the people to help you. Good job. It's the same like not providing more detail, because it's all too damn easy, to help find an answer. If it's so easy, you wouldn't have the problem. ;o) Well at least there are people willing to help so good luck with solving your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use two-way binding in numeric template and it only accepts something like Double, it can set value to number. But no one can be sure without seeing full code. It's possible that your own code does something wrong.
To understand things better, create your own control, derived from the ContentControl, and use it in your sample. Then override control methods OnContentxxxChanged, insert breakpoints there and debug your application. You should understand, what's going on with your data and with template selector. When application stops on breakpoint, carefully check all values and look at stack trace. To debug bindings you can insert IValueConverters, it would give you place in code, where you can check values.

I really suggest you to make the simplest working thing first, and then go to more complicated things such as textboxes with two-way bindings to some property of some control which you didn't show in your question. Here is a working version with TextBlocks:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public void OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.DataContext == null)
            this.DataContext = "Hallo";

        else if (this.DataContext is string)
            this.DataContext = 123;

        else if (this.DataContext is int)
            this.DataContext = null;
    }
}
public class MyTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate TextTemplate {get; set;}

    public DataTemplate NumericTemplate {get; set;}

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (item is string)
        {
            return this.TextTemplate;
        }
        else
        {
            return this.NumericTemplate;
        }
    }
}
```

and xaml:

```
    <Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="numericDataTemplate">
            <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Text="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="textDataTemplate">
            <TextBlock Foreground="Green" Text="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <local:MyTemplateSelector x:Key="dataTemplateSelector"
                             TextTemplate="{StaticResource textDataTemplate}"
                             NumericTemplate="{StaticResource numericDataTemplate}"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Click="OnClick" Content="Click Me" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <ContentControl Name="contentCtrl"
                Content="{Binding}" 
                Width="300" Height="100" 
                ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource dataTemplateSelector}" />
        </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Compare with your code. When you inherit from DataTemplateSelector, you should override SelectTemplate method and don't invent methods with other names. All controls such as ContentControl will only use SelectTemplate. Etc..

Obviously, all works and DataTemplateSelector does nothing wrong. I suppose, your problem is somewhere in your data and bindings

And look at your OnClick method - it always sets DataContext to null

Comment: sorry but i dont know what are you talking about.. there is no more code to show.. its really a simple application.. i wish i could show you more code but there isnt.. i am not creating or customizing something its all pure wpf and xaml

Comment: sorry, in your question I don't see any code at all about the stuff which you use as DataContext, or how do you change it. From your snippets you can't reconstruct your application and run it. There is no telepathy out here.

Comment: i did a bunch of testing and i figured out that when template is null that gets reseting all the objects which used to be inside the template for whatever reason. i create few tests and that behaviour occured each time. seems its wpf internal and i cant change it. but thanks anyways for your advices to debug everything in small pieces.. i did so.. its actually a common way to debug everything.. and i also think that everbody should first debug before posting questions here. sorry if my code didnt compile at first place..

Comment: it's absolutely correct behavior and it doesn't related to template selector. When you set different content template, DataContext of the previous one gets cleared, the other behaviour would result in memory leaks.

Comment: very true.. it sets values to null